# How to pass an enum parameter with expression language?

Tags: jsf, enums, el

I have following snippet of JSF code:

```
<p:selectManyMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{templateBean.getTemplates(TemplateType.TEXTBLOCK)}"
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

How is it possible to pass a `enum`-Parameter to the `getTemplates()`
-function?

The backing bean has this function:

```
public List<Template> getTemplates(TemplateType templateType)
```

The `TemplateType` is an `enum`:

```
public enum TemplateType {
    ANSWER,
    TEXTBLOCK;
}
```

Only way, thats coming to my mind, is to make another function which returns me the actual option of that `enum`-type, but that seems some kind of senseless. I also tried to give the `enum`-Class a `Scope`, but I can not access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass the enum value as string. EL has builtin coercion for that.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{templateBean.getTemplates('TEXTBLOCK')}" />
```

The `<o:importConstants>` is generally only handy whenever you want to have all enum values in the view, e.g. as dropdown items as below:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{TemplateType}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I think thats the best choice for my use case. But from where EL knows, that `TEXTBLOCK` is from the type `TemplateType`. Just from the function itself? And where do I find such information about EL or is it just your experience, that you know such things?

Comment: [EL spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) chapter 1.21. It's by the way called "method", not "function".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the enum like that (`TemplateType.TEXTBLOCK`) you should try the [o:importConstants](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) (by [omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/))

Put the following on your page

```
<o:importConstants type="com.my.package.name.TemplateType" />
```

Then use it like this

```
<p:selectManyMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{templateBean.getTemplates(TemplateType.TEXTBLOCK)}"
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Of course you can always use the enum the plain text like this:

```
value="#{templateBean.getTemplates('TEXTBLOCK')}"
```